# Can I Speed-Up This VBA to Move Emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have Outlook VBA that does exactly what I want it to do. It moves the previous workday's emails to a new folder, and it does this within a secondary email inbox.

What I'm looking for is advice on how to make it move the emails faster.

If I manually copied all the emails to another folder it would take a few seconds. When I run the code it takes minutes. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Yesterdays_Emails()

'***Creates a new folder named yesterdays date under the inbox***

 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim strMailboxName As String
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim xDay As String
 Dim XDate As Date
 Dim thatDay As String
 strMailboxName = "Deductions Backup"


    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        XDate = Date - 3
    Else
        XDate = Date - 1
    End If

    thatDay = WeekdayName(Weekday(XDate))

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
 Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("Inbox")
 Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add(XDate & " " & thatDay)

'***Finds all emails in the inbox from yesterday and moves them to the created folder***

    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim i As Long

        Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
              CStr(XDate) & _
             " 12:00AM' AND [ReceivedTime] < '" & _
              CStr(XDate + 1) & " 12:00AM'"

        Debug.Print Filter

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
    Set Inbox = myFolder.Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Debug.Print Items(i)
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Item.Move myNewFolder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any idea why this is so much slower than manually moving the items, or how to make this run quicker? I don't see why it should take any longer than if it was being done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering your mails before you look at and move them, try simply looking at them and then deciding whether to move them or not.

For example a simple for Loop like this could do the trick:

```
For Each item In Inbox.Items
     If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
         If item.ReceivedTime < Date And item.ReceivedTime > Date - 1 Then
             item.Move myNewFolder
         End If
     End If
 Next
```

Filtering something is incredibly slow.

Note however that I am not 100% certain that `Date - 1` works for mails received shortly after midnight though.

Comment: are you sure that the filtering is really the problem though? I ask that only because my understanding of my code is that the filter is applied once before any items are moved, not reapplied after each move. When I watch this run, items start to be moved immediately. its just that there is time between item 1....then 2....then 3. Sometimes 2 or 3 seconds between each. So I think the slowness is happening during the item.move and not the filtering....maybe

Comment: But if I manually select all the items and drop them in the subfolder, it takes like 3 seconds to move all 200+, but it would take like 5 minutes for the code to do it all.

Comment: @TBoulz In that case I misunderstood where your code was lagging. I thought it was the whole process not only the moving part. Please note, though, that filtering is always slow anyway. I’ll edit my answer if something comes to mind, that you could try!

Comment: thanks for taking a look, I put a debug timer in, and really nothing seems to take that long. filter was 1 sec. Moving each item was under a second, sometimes took a little more. Main issue is that sometimes when moving the item, it gets hungup and takes 2 or 3 seconds. Then after moving about 40 emails it seems to completely freeze.
Even without the hangups and freezing, if it continue at 1 second per item that is still really slow considering I can drag and drop 200 items and it takes probably less than 2 seconds. Frustrating that it is so much quicker manually

Comment: is there a way, in Outlook, to select the first email showing from a date, and then select all the email items below it? like a shift+control+down function? it doesnt seem to work in outlook, but maybe something like that so i would only be doing 1 move, instead of 200+ moves.